# How to add numbers to ArrayList or List<int> from textbox

Tags: c#, arraylist, textbox

I want to add numbers to ArrayList or List from textBox.
I think that when user writes numbers to textBox , textBoxe's text converts to string and splits on ArrayList elements. But I have no idea how to do it. I've tried very long time and always had an InvalidCastException.

```
    ArrayList Integers = new ArrayList();
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Length; i++)
        {
            Integers.Add();
        }
    }
```

Give me a hint please

Comment: Until you don't show what you have tried there is nothing to fix. How are the numbers separated? Are these numbers integeres or can they contain group- or decimal separators? If so, what culture are you using? Show sample input.

Comment: "when user writes numbers to textbox" so which event do you plan to use to add the textbox value to the list? when the textbox changes? when the textbox loses focus? when you click on a button?

Comment: @Innat3 ButtonClick

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry , I forgot to paste a code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare an Integer List inside your Form class and use TryParse to convert the TextBox string to integer and manage possible exceptions when you add values

```
    List<int> myNumbers = new List<int>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        foreach (string str in textBox1.Text.Split(' '))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(str, out i))
                myNumbers.Add(int.Parse(str));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you show your code It would be hard to suggest something just a hint

TextItem is by default a string so Might be Your List is an int Try:

```
var a =int.Parse(textbox1.Text);
myList.Add(a);
```

Would be helpful for you.

Comment: this will generate an exception when parsing an invalid numeric value

Comment: He asked to add numbers. Not an AlphaNumeric values

Comment: I know, but you always want to take human error into account when coding xD

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare your list globally as

   ```
   List<int> listInt = new List<int>();
   ```

In the click event of your button, add following code

```
 if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
                listInt.Add(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
```

This would only insert Int32 values. Any other input would give an exception.

Comment: How it will throw exception?

Comment: If you enter a string value in your textbox, that wouldn't be able to parse into int32. any other double or float would get truncated.